# Logging apt/dpkg activity to syslog

Tags: apt, dpkg, syslog, rsyslog

My goal is to log **apt/dpkg** activity using **syslog (rsyslog)**, so that log entries are sent to central syslog server.

dpkg writes to `/var/log/dpkg.log`, apt writes to `/var/log/apt` directory.

I did some research and it seems that apt nor dpkg are able to use syslog. The only option is to use rsyslog "Text File Input Module" feature (http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/modules/imfile.html), which periodically checks log file for new content.

`/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg` configuration file has `log` option, but there is no manual page for dpkg.cfg options and features.

Is really **rsyslog imfile** the only option?

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that. Also, do you want it to log to `syslog` instead or in addition to the places it logs to?

Comment: I need it, because our company's policy requires to have central syslog server with log events from all servers in one place. rsyslog takes care of distributing events, so I need to get apt+dpkg events (installed/removed/updated packages) to rsyslog process.

Comment: I assume you've seen http://blog.actbluetech.com/2012/07/logging-dpkg-to-syslog.html.

Comment: Yes I did, but it logs only packages names without activity details. imfile is better for that. I just wonder why apt/dpkg does not have natural ability to talk to syslog process.

Comment: File wishlist bugs, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

For dpkg this can be done by adding

```
status-logger "logger -t dpkg -p info"
```

to */etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg*. Since apt-get calls dpkg, also apt-get/apt actions get logged. See `man logger` for adjusting the information logged to the syslog.

I am using this ansible task to update the configs:

```
- name: dpkg syslog
  lineinfile:
   dest: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg
   line: 'status-logger "logger -t dpkg -p info"'
```

If you are using the systemd journal it is convenient to check the logs via

```
journalctl SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=dpkg
```

Comment: Nice, though the ansible task needs `become: yes` to avoid an error: `FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The destination directory (/etc/dpkg) is not writable by the current user. Error was: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/etc/dpkg/.ansible_tmppkCGRodpkg.cfg'"}`

Answer (score 0):

Modifying where dpkg logs its output is possible through the `--log` option. This only allows filenames. DPKG was built as a simple and efficient tool to manipulate packages, so not having logger that complicates stuff is a plus. The simplest way would be that you write to a file and syslog reads from that file as you already know.

You can use `status-fd` to send the status to a file descriptor like `/dev/log` or `status-logger` to have a middleman that sends the entries to the syslog.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `status-logger`/`status-fd` does not always have the same output as the log file specified by `log` directive. And there is even `alternatives.log` hard-coded in the source code of dpkg that you cannot change without recompiling.

So I tried to replace log files with fifo, and pump the log content to journald. Thanks to the flexibility of systemd, this can be done without extra dependencies.

1. Prepare a bash script at `/usr/local/libexec/fifo2journal`. Don't forget `chmod +x`. This script is effectively `cat` with hard-coded 60s timeout. If there is no data (or no line-feed) available in stdin, this script just output the partial line it read and quit (to save resource).

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   while :; do
       if IFS= read -r -t 60; then
           printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"
       else
           printf "%s" "$REPLY"
           exit 0
       fi
   done
   ```
2. Prepare systemd units. (socket activation with fifo on filesystem)

   a. `/etc/systemd/system/fifo2journal@.socket`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=fifo at %f

   [Socket]
   ListenFIFO=%f
   SocketMode=0660

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sockets.target
   ```

   b. `/etc/systemd/system/fifo2journal@.service`

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=fifo to journal for %f
   Requires=fifo2journal@%i.socket

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/local/libexec/fifo2journal
   StandardInput=socket
   StandardOutput=journal
   SyslogIdentifier=%f
   SyslogFacility=user
   ```
3. Remove existing log files on disk (backup if you cares). Enable & start systemd socket unit.

   ```
   systemctl daemon-reload
   for FILEPATH in /var/log/dpkg.log /var/log/alternatives.log; do
       rm -f "$FILEPATH"
       UNIT_NAME=$(systemd-escape --template=fifo2journal@.socket --path "$FILEPATH")
       systemctl enable "$UNIT_NAME"
       systemctl start "$UNIT_NAME"
   done
   ```

Now you can watch the journal (`journalctl -f -t /var/log/dpkg.log`) and try writing to it (`echo hello >/var/log/dpkg.log`).

logrotate will treat fifo as empty log, and does nothing.

Keep in mind that this method requires systemd running for socket activation. It may cause unexpected consequence if systemd is not running and you try to open a (closed) fifo without `O_NONBLOCK`, especially if you are rescuing your rootfs via chroot.

There is a potential problem if you are upgrading systemd and socket activation is not ready in the 60s time window for whatever reason, and any thread that tries to open the fifo without `O_NONBLOCK` hangs. I wish this will never happen.